# Better usepackage{setspace} or linespread{}?

Tags: line-spacing

Since all answers are from 2012 or earlier and the setspace-package is archived:

Do I use this package or do I use linespread for line spacing?

Is there a difference between those two options i.e. when it comes to header/footer?

Comment: `l2tabu` recommends `setspace` because it cares for spacing in footnotes or list environments (§1.4)

Comment: @Bernard and linespread does not do that? I didn't find anything about that.

Comment: I don't think so. Also, there's often some misunderstanding about, e.g. `double-spacing`: contrary to the naive point of view, it is not the same as `\linespread{2}`, because typograph take into account optical effects, and `setspace` also takes care of this.

Comment: @Bernard so is it still okay to use setspace although it doesn't seem to be maintained anymore?

Comment: It didn't change because there's nothing to be changed, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

when use

```
\begin{spaceing}{1.2}
\end{spacing}
```

the effect is almost the same as

```
\linespread{1.2}
```

The setspace package was developed before LaTeX2E developed the interface of linespread change. Now it's 2020, You can use the latter in LaTeX2E.

By the way, **the linespread = baselineskip * baselinestretch.**

For example, if font size = 10 pt, baselineskip = 12 pt, which is defined in size10.clo. Then you use

```
\linespread{2.0}
```

The line spacing would be 24 pt, not 20 pt.